# Avatar for search bar

Tags: php, database, laravel, search

I have been trying to populate my search bar with a little gravatar image beside it. However, it is not showing. Provided down below is my code please any help will do.

Results.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h3> Your search for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h3>

    @if (!$users->count())
      <p>No results found, sorry.</p>
    @else

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          @foreach ($users as $user)
              @include('user/partials/userblock')
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
      @endif
    @stop
```

userblock.blade.php

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="
    {{ $user->getAvatarUrl() }}">
  </a>

  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
    @if ($user->location)
      <p>{{ $user->location }}</p>
      @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace Kermode;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password','gender',

    ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getName()
    {
      if ($this->first_name && $this->last_name) {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
      }
      if ($this->first_name) {
        return $this->first_name;
      }

      return null;
      }

    public function getNameOrUsername()
      {
        return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
      }

      public function getFirstNameOrUsername()
      {
        return $this->first_name ?: $this->username;
      }

      public function getAvatarUrl()
        {
          return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5($this->email) }}
          ?d=mm&s=40";
        }
}
```

SearchController.php

```
<?php

namespace Kermode\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Kermode\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
  public function getResults(Request $request)
  {
    $query = $request->input('query');

    if (!$query) {
      return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    $users = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name)"),
    'LIKE', "%$query%")
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE' , "%$query%")
    ->get();

    return view('search.results', compact('users'));
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am new to a web based applications.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxx

Answer (score 0):

in your User class, try not to use blade.

```
    public function getAvatarUrl()
    {
      $md5Email = md5($this->email);
      return sprintf("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/%s?d=mm&s=40", $md5Email); 
    }
```

Additional tips:

- In your PHP entity classes (such as User in your case), never use 3rd party template such as twig, blade, etc. leave the representation handled by "View" part of the application. This could benefit you when you want to switch templating engine.

Comment: Another possibility is to have getEmail in your User class, and in your blade userblock.blade.php you can have like `src=https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5($user->getEmail()}}?d=mm&s=40`